# Using training data to fine-tune BERT-base, the loss does not decrease

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I selected a total of 24478 scenic spot description data from 237 categories to fine-tune BERT-base, and the average loss remained about 5. Specifically, the amount of data for each category is less than or equal to 200, and learning rate: 10-6 or 10-7. Other hyper-parameters are consistent with the original experiment of BERT. What factors may cause losses to not converge?

I selected 800 news data from 10 categories from the public news data set as training set. After 10 epochs of training with learning rate of 10-5, the model achieves 97% accurance on 400 test samples. After verifying the validity of the method, I selected a total of 3050 scenic spot description data from 14 categories to fine-tune BERT-base. After 10 epochs of training with learning rate of 10-6, the training loss converges to 0.5 and the model achieves 83% accurance on 230 test samples(the loss does not decrease with learning rate of 10-5).

Comment: What is the batch size used?
Also, are the training examples well-shuffled?

Comment: You are on the right lines！After shuffling the training data, loss begins to decreasing. The model achieves 53% accurance on 4900 test samples after 5 epochs. And the batch size is 32, maybe i can reduce it to 16 or 8 for futher promoting loss convergence.

Comment: For training, it is recommended to use higher batch size.